# Why is CORS complaining: 'No Access-Control-Allow-Origin' / '500 (Internal Server Error)', even though it looks configured correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net

### Briefing

I am aware what CORS is, and how it works.
Lately, I performed a big update on my application.
Since then, my Client Application cannot connect to the backend due to the CORS error.

My Admin Application has no problems connecting to the BE.
I compared the web.configs and a couple of other files, and cannot see much of a difference in the Client configuration.

(Admin: FE=MVC5/ASP | BE= ASP.NET)

(Client: FE= Angular 8.1 | BE= ASP.NET)

Changelog of what happened in the update:

- Implemented Unity Dependency Injection for the Web Controllers
- Made all the WebControllers inherit from a BaseController that handles the DI
- Updated a couple of Microsoft.AspNet "Web" Nugets from v5.2.3 -> 5.2.7

Cors has worked without any issue before this. I looked at my file changes in my git client and could not find any changes to files that could relate to this CORS issue at first glance.

*If you need more information or more insight into specific files, let me know in the comments and I will provide them.*

---

### Code Snippets

Config-based CORS configuration is commented out (by a previous developer) in **Web.Config**:

```xml
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <!--<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:4200" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />-->
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

When I uncomment this, and change the origin to my server,
the "No-Access-Control-Origin" error disappers, but I get error 500 (Internal Server Error) instead.

CORS is configured via the **WebApiConfig**, this class gets executed and loaded, I checked that with a breakpoint. I tried both `new EnableCorsAttribute("subdomain.ourdomain.com",...` and `new EnableCorsAttribute("*",...` ...To no avail.

```cs
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            cors.SupportsCredentials = true;
            config.EnableCors(cors);

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Obviously I have googled, and found the [Enable-Cors.org](https://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html) for ASP.NET, which all looks really good.

I have checked my WebApiConfig against what is described as the global CORS approach on that page, and to me it looks like that my WebApiConfig.cs is configured correctly.

I am a little stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that CORS was just fine (a couple slight adjustments, rebuilds and redeploys did the trick)

But the main culprit (Error 500) was coming from missing assemblies, that Visual Studio 2019's WebDeploy did not correctly move to the server.

Manually copying the files over to the server fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that you have not applied the Attribute to your controllers as per the guidance [in microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

For the global solution, you need to go with the `ICorsPolicyProviderFactory`

Create first your own Wrapper around the attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class MyCorsPolicyAttribute : Attribute, ICorsPolicyProvider 
{
    private CorsPolicy _policy;

    public MyCorsPolicyAttribute()
    {
        // Create a CORS policy.
        _policy = new CorsPolicy
        {
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true
        };

        // Add allowed origins.
        _policy.Origins.Add("your.domain1");
        _policy.Origins.Add("your.domain2");
    }

    public Task<CorsPolicy> GetCorsPolicyAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_policy);
    }
}
```

Then create the factory provider:

```
public class CorsPolicyFactory : ICorsPolicyProviderFactory
{
    ICorsPolicyProvider _provider = new MyCorsPolicyProvider();

    public ICorsPolicyProvider GetCorsPolicyProvider(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        return _provider;
    }
}
```

And last but not least register it in your settings

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetCorsPolicyProviderFactory(new CorsPolicyFactory());
        config.EnableCors();

        // ...
    }
}
```

Let me know how this works for you.

Comment: Doesn't the described method under https://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html / Enabling Globally already cover everything to configure CORS globally without having to annotate any of my webcontrollers?

Comment: In all honesty it should be. Can you please do a couple of checks for me? 1st - check wether or not the headers are set in your current configuration. 2nd - annotate with the attribute and see if it works, before setting the custom provider.

Comment: It turned out that CORS was just fine after fiddling around slightly, and that the Error 500 was coming from a missing assembly.

Comment: Perfect! Glad to hear that you figured it out.

Comment: I feel obliged to mark my answer as the answer due to SO rules, but I still upvoted your answer to appreciate the time and effort you put into your answer. Thank you!